# How to compute Mutual Information

Tags: self-study, logarithm, mutual-information, cooccurrence

I am absolutely new to MI (and just really bad at it too!) and was wondering if someone could explain to me how to resolve this question.
"Say word A occurs once per 1'000 words (i.e, Freq. (A)=0,001) and word be once per 100'000 words. They co-occur once per 2'000'000 words. Compute their MI."

The MI formula I have been given is this one :

[image: screenshot of formula]

I believe I have understood how to place the numbers in my calculation, but I have not understood where the '2'000'000 words' appear in it.

Thanks in advance for your help, I'm very much lost!

Comment: It seems that you have three numbers and three slots. The pigeonhole principle might tell you where the 2'000'000 belongs.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: Hi Ella, if you found this answer helpful, then please consider
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Answer (score 2):

Converting my comment into an answer:

It seems that you have three numbers and three slots. The pigeonhole principle might tell you where the 2'000'000 belongs.